# Worklight Server 6.1 configuration-tool.sh error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, rhel, worklight-server

I have installed Worklight Server on RHEL 6.4.

The menu shortcut that was created for the Server Configuration Tool has the path:

```
/opt/IBM/Worklight/shortcuts/configuration-tool.sh
```

The actual script was installed to:

```
/opt/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/install/shortcuts/configuration-tool.sh
```

I changed the launcher to open the correct script but it silently fails to run.
When running the script from the terminal, I get the following error:

```
[root@lr60xm4 ~]# /opt/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/install/shortcuts/configuration-tool.sh 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JavaVersion6
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: JavaVersion6
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:677)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
Could not find the main class: JavaVersion6.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.worklight.config.util.helper.JVMBitness
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.worklight.config.util.helper.JVMBitness
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:677)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
Could not find the main class: com.ibm.worklight.config.util.helper.JVMBitness.  Program will exit.
/opt/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/install/shortcuts/configuration-tool.sh: fatal error: unsupported platform
```

**Is this expected behavior? 
Anything I can do to resolve?**

I know I can use Ant, but unfortunately I have almost no experience using it.

Here's some system details:

```
[root@lr60xm4 ~]# java -version
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxz6460sr15-20131017_01(SR15))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Linux s390x-64 jvmxz6460sr15-20131016_170922 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20131016_170922
JIT  - r9_20130920_46510ifx2
GC   - GA24_Java6_SR15_20131016_1337_B170922)
JCL  - 20131015_01

[root@lr60xm4 ~]# uname -a; cat /etc/system*
Linux lr60xm4.dal-ebit.ihost.com 2.6.32-358.el6.s390x #1 SMP Tue Jan 29 12:06:31 EST 2013 s390x s390x s390x GNU/Linux
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:6server:ga:server
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `/opt/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/install/shortcuts/configuration-tool.sh` is not meant to be executed; it is just a template. Use the file `/opt/IBM/Worklight/shortcuts/configuration-tool.sh` instead; this is the real one.

Comment: Sorry, there is not file named configuration-tool.sh in that directory:


`$ ls /opt/IBM/Worklight/shortcuts/
ant  ant.bat  application-center.sh  application-center.url  open-url.sh`

Comment: There is no file configuration-tool.sh in /opt/IBM/Worklight/shortcuts/ on your system, because the Server Configuration Tool is not supported on Linux/s390 (= Linux/z) in the Worklight 6.1 release. See [the documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc%2Fdeploy%2Fc_using_server_config_tool.html).